# Bibliography horizontal line to replace author's name

Tags: biblatex

The original question of this thread (Dashed=true option in biblatex gives biblatex2.sty error), was addressed by @JosephWright below, and should be kept for future reference.

As I understood better the nature of the problem, I decided to edit the original title and provide an answer to it below. I also deleted my old comments so as to clean up the thread.

I use `\RequirePackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex`}

Comment: `dashed` is an options for individual styles, not the `biblatex` core: does style `sbl` say it supports `dashed`? (I'm not familiar with the `sbl` style.)

Comment: Please add that (important) information to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dashed` option is not built in to `biblatex` but is provided by some of the standard styles: `authoryear` and derivatives. In `authoryear.bbx` you will find

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{dashed}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}%
     \renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{\savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}
    {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}}}
```

along with

```
\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
```

and use of this new macro in various places.

Thus to provide the `dashed` option a custom style must either load `authoryear` and make changes *or* contain the above lines (or a variant thereof).

Answer (score 0):

This macro, inserted in my `.def` file, produces a horizontal line, period, and space for different bibliography items by the same author.

The height of the line can be adjusted by "ex" and the length by "em"

```
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \leavevmode\raise -0.4ex\hbox to 5.5em{\hrulefill}.\space}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}

\newbibmacro*{cbx:dashcheck}[2]{#2}

\newbibmacro*{dashcheck}[2]{%
  \usebibmacro{cbx:dashcheck}{#1}{#2}}

\newbibmacro*{savehash}{}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]