# Enabling dashed option in phys style

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I'm new here, sorry for eventual formatting errors :)

I'm currently using this `biblatex` setting.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex,
citestyle=alphabetic,
bibstyle=phys,
natbib=true]{biblatex}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\references.bib}
@article{np30,
title={{China Sea Pilot, Vol. 1}},
author={{United Kingdom Hydrographic Office [UKHO]}},
journal={\textit{Admiralty Sailing Directions 30} 8th ed. (2010)},
}

@article{np31,
title={{China Sea Pilot, Vol. 2}},
author={{United Kingdom Hydrographic Office [UKHO]}},
journal={\textit{Admiralty Sailing Directions 31} 9th ed. (2010)},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

However, this style does not support the `dashed` option.
Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would this be the same problem as [Enabling dashed option for biblatex-ieee style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70411/106162)

Comment: Thanks! I read that question! Actually with `biblatex-ieee` style I do not encounter difficulties in dashing!

Comment: Ok, if you could try adding a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that clearly illustrates where you would like to have dashing that might be helpful.

Comment: Printing bibliography in alphabetical style (as the code above suggests), I would like that author to appear only for the first entry, and be dashed for the others! I edited the post for the MWEB!

Comment: Does [Bibliography horizontal line to replace author's name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199881/106162) help, I think this asks the same thing but I can't get Joseph Wright's answer to work with your MWE.

Comment: See also [Make biblatex numeric style use line in bibliography entries for same author?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335960/35864) which works for the generic `numeric` style. (I'd venture that the changes needed for your style are minimal.)

Comment: Does `citestyle=alphabetic, bibstyle=phys,` actually make sense?

Comment: @moewe the [http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335960/35864] works of course, but then the output is quite far, so at that point I should intervene on the style file. This woul be of course the most elegant solution, but it will require a bit of time! So for the moment I think I will continue looking for something simplier!

I do not remember how I arrived at the combination of `citestyle=alphabetic` and `bicstyle=phys`, but actually the output is what I needed, exept for the absence of the `dashed` option!

Comment: What do you mean by 'far', do you mean that the dash is quite long? You could leave out the `\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\rule{3em}{0.4pt}\hskip 0.16667em plus 0.01em minus 0.002em\relax \addcomma}` line. But I suppose Joseph's answer is pretty much the same.

Comment: I mean that I have to change manually separators (period for commas), when the style use italic, etc., since (at least when I process my file) the result looks different! Regarding Joseph's answer, I've encoutered several errors, I'm going through them now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could add the same code as in the `ieee` style:

```
\makeatletter
% Support for dashed author name replacement
\InitializeBibliographyStyle{\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{\savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}

% Bibliography macros
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {%
      \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}
        {\bibnamedash\addcomma\space}
        {\printnames{author}}%
      \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%  
      \iffieldundef{authortype}
        {}
        {%
          \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        }%
    }
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}%
}
\makeatother
```

which will enable dashes.

Comment: This isn't in the `phys` style as it's not used by the APS or AIP, and as they are numerical-based styles so removing author names doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I know it does not make sense, but it's what I'm asked for! Anyway the code seems not working to me, several errors occurr, and I managed to solve only some of them

Comment: @Jerack The code I've posted works for me edited into your example after the `\usepackage` line, with only a typo to fix in your code (`\references` should be `references`). If you are seeing other issues, please edit the question to show them.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem! The string conflicted with another personalised command, but I managed to edit! Thank you! :D